How does Terraform do implicit conversion of an empty map in a conditional expression?
Ran into something weird:
locals {
  outer_map = {
    inner_map = {
      key = "value"
    }
  }
}

resource "random_string" "default" {
  length = lookup(local.outer_map, "inner_map", {}) != {} ? 4 : 2
}

This works fine, length is 4.
locals {
  outer_map = {}
}

This is also fine, length is 2 as expected. But:
locals {
  outer_map = true ? {
    inner_map = {
      key = "value"
    }
  } : {}
}

This throws an error:
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│
│   on test.tf line 10, in resource "random_string" "default":
│   10:   length = lookup(local.outer_map, "inner_map", {}) != {} ? 4 : 2
│     ├────────────────
│     │ while calling lookup(inputMap, key, default...)
│
│ Invalid value for "default" parameter: the default value must have the same type as the map elements.
╵

I'm aware of the type conversions inside a conditional expression, but I can't fathom how it would convert an empty map and a map of a map into something that is incompatible with an empty map. Is it intended behavior that the error should be thrown? Is it a bug in Terraform?

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, here's the answer straight from HashiCorp: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/35662

Try using the can function:
resource "random_string" "default" {
  length = can(local.outer_map.inner_map) ? 4 : 2
}

Example 1 - map with inner map
locals {
  outer_map = {
    inner_map = {
      key = "value"
    }
  }
}

resource "random_string" "default" {
  length = can(local.outer_map.inner_map) ? 4 : 2
}

output "outer_map" {
  value = local.outer_map
}

output "random_string_length" {
  value = random_string.default.length
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_string.default will be created
  + resource "random_string" "default" {
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + length      = 4
      + lower       = true
      + min_lower   = 0
      + min_numeric = 0
      + min_special = 0
      + min_upper   = 0
      + number      = true
      + numeric     = true
      + result      = (known after apply)
      + special     = true
      + upper       = true
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + outer_map            = {
      + inner_map = {
          + key = "value"
        }
    }
  + random_string_length = 4

Example 2 - using an empty map
locals {
  outer_map = {}
}

resource "random_string" "default" {
  length = can(local.outer_map.inner_map) ? 4 : 2
}

output "outer_map" {
  value = local.outer_map
}

output "random_string_length" {
  value = random_string.default.length
}

Running terraform plan:
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution
plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # random_string.default will be created
  + resource "random_string" "default" {
      + id          = (known after apply)
      + length      = 2
      + lower       = true
      + min_lower   = 0
      + min_numeric = 0
      + min_special = 0
      + min_upper   = 0
      + number      = true
      + numeric     = true
      + result      = (known after apply)
      + special     = true
      + upper       = true
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Changes to Outputs:
  + outer_map            = {}
  + random_string_length = 2


Thank you, but I'm not looking for a solution (I found that using null as the default value for the lookup works as well). The question of my post is why my snippet doesn't work. Is it intended behavior that the error should be thrown? Is it a bug in Terraform?
